How to change the icon displayed in the password.app
Want to change this icon because I visually want a visual differentiation from the passwords / accounts I have for a website.


The icon displayed in the Password app comes from the URL you paste when creating a password.
To use a different icon, pick a site with an icon you like and paste that URL. After creating the entry, edit it to correct the website URL.

That doesn’t appear to work after the entry has already been created.
